# node-html-pdf not show image in PDF

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, node-html-pdf

I am trying generate PDF from simple code, but no show image.
Help me please.

code

```js
pdf.create("Hello <img src='j4.jpg' />").toFile('./pdf/cotizacion.pdf', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("File created successfully ");
    }
});
```

**Result**:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Does it change if you try as `<img src='file://j4.jpg'>`?

Answer (score 2):

Can you something like this, since its not reading your image, its taking it as a string.

```
    <img src={{IMG_URL}} style="width:100%"/>
```

Or you can put base64 of image like:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, {{BASE64_DATA_OF_IMG}}" style="width:100%"/>
```

This will read your image in pdf.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing I noticed the images are shown in pdf if they are served somewhere, every attempt with `file://path_to_file` or relative path failed.

Instead I serve the image on a server http://localhost:3000/images/logo.svg

and I use `<img src="http://localhost:3000/images/logo.svg" style="width:100%"/>`